# The color theme of my app is not changing

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning how to code with Dart to make apps, and when I want to change the color theme of my app to a different color it stays the same.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: ' My first app',
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.orange),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So you've saved the file and it has hot-reloaded?  Do you have any material widgets that take their colors from the theme, like appbar or button?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ThemeData **primarySwatch** property to change the app color scheme.
With primaryColor you only change one value, and widgets use different shades of the color.

**Example:**

```
final primaryColor=const Color(0xFFa671da);
final primaryColorPalette=const {
 50:Color.fromRGBO(166, 113, 218, .1),
 100:Color.fromRGBO(166, 113, 218, .2),
 200:Color.fromRGBO(166, 113, 218, .3),
 300:Color.fromRGBO(166, 113, 218, .4),
 400:Color.fromRGBO(166, 113, 218, .5),
 500:Color.fromRGBO(166, 113, 218, .6),
 600:Color.fromRGBO(166, 113, 218, .7),
 700:Color.fromRGBO(166, 113, 218, .8),
 800:Color.fromRGBO(166, 113, 218, .9),
 900:Color.fromRGBO(166, 113, 218, 1),
};

...

primarySwatch: MaterialColor(primaryColor.value,primaryColorPalette),
```